# how do i redirect any TCP domain request which inlcudes "msedge.net"?

Tags: windows-10

I want to redirect all TCP requests for domains which has "msedge.net" in it to 127.0.0.1

I'm using windows 10 OS

I'm guessing i need some sort of local proxy

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in Windows but you can go to your routers settings and block it from parental control. Settings will differ from router to router but when you go to parental control type `*.msedge.net`.